# Civi 5.6.0 - wrong css z-index on Activities page when creating/viewing activity

Tags: activities, css

CiviCRM 5.6.0
Joomla 3.8.12
php 7.0.32

On the activities tab of a contact, when you create or view an activity, the panel which pops up is displayed behind the black CiviCRM menu bar, and also behind the main Joomla menu bar. The same happens with when you view an activity in the Find Activities results page.

Not a big deal, but needs fixing.

Update: it's not only the activities page/tab. It seems to be every page. Wherever there's a pop-up window or a pull-down menu, the black CiviCRM menu is in front of it.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshot of the menu?

Comment: Works OK on my 5.6.0 with Drupal

Comment: Added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Jern,

This is because of Joomla theme css might be conflicting with CiviCRM css. Try switching the theme to default one if you can replicate the same issue. I tried on my local machine on 5.6.0 and couldn't replicate the issue. Also try to perform CiviCRM cleanup cache if it helps.

Try after reverting the [commit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/8aa67b8570e786f5d0348d2d1bedeeebca17fafb) in your core file.

Comment: I've tried it on two installations, which have completely different themes, but both show the same problem. Both are running on php 7.0. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Actually, what I wrote is nonsense. It's the back-end template which matters here. Both installations are using the default back-end template Isis.

Comment: We have seen this issue, too using Joomla 3.8.x and CiviCRM 5.6.0.  Our live site is still running CiviCRM 5.3.2, and does not show the problem. We are using PHP 7.1.x on some sites, and 7.2.x on a development site.  Both show the issue.  Clearing caches did not solve the issue.

Comment: Jern, I have updated my answer with a link of commit to revert. In short you will need to add those removed lines back into Joomla.css file. Do let us know how it goes, if it works then i will create a regression issue against it.